# building a 3by3n matrix from two <nx1> column vectors

Tags: matlab, loops, optimization

I have two column vectors each of size `<nx1>`. The `config` vector contains the numbers `721,722,723 and 724` only and the `length` vector,of size `<nx1>` contains numbers only. I need to build the matrix Z, which is of size `<3x3n>`:
`note:matrices a,b,c and d are each <3x3> matrices.` It's difficult to put the rule in words here, let me try and give an example first:

`length=[1 2 3],config=[721 722 723],a=eye(3),b=ones(3),c=magic(3);`

> ```
> z=[ 1     0     0     2     2     2    24     3    18
>     0     1     0     2     2     2     9    15    21
>     0     0     1     2     2     2    12    27     6]
> ```
>
> that is, if config(i) is 722 and length(i) is 2, append 2*matrix_a to the z matrix and so on.

I did the following:

```
     z=[0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0];
    for i=1:3
    [~,col]=size(z);
      if config(i)==721
       z(:,col+[1:3])=length(i)*a
      end
      if config(i)==722
       z(:,col+[1:3])=length(i)*b
      end
      if config(i)==723
       z(:,col+[1:3])=length(i)*c
      end
    end
    z=z(:,4:end)
```

but isn't there a better loopless,vectorized method?

Comment: I would recommend you to copy the code exactly as you ran it. I will fix some typos.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Fixed the typos. It should be clearer now.

Comment: Why don't you just use `[a b c]`? Read this as: which things exactly need to be variable?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin The above is just an example. My original n is  a 123x1 vector. There is nothing variable here, its just" check config element, then length element and based on these 2 values infer what the corresponding 3x3 submatrix is to be placed in the Z array".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you still need this information, but I find the solution:

```
config = [722 722 723 723 721];
lenght=[3 4 5 6 7];
a=eye(3);b=ones(3);c=magic(3);
d1 = kron( ~rem(config, 721).*lenght, a);
d2 = kron( ~rem(config, 722).*lenght, b);
d3 = kron( ~rem(config, 723).*lenght, c);
result = d1 + d2 + d3;
```

And result for my data:

```
a =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1

b =

     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1

c =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

result =

     3     3     3     4     4     4    40     5    30    48     6    36     7     0     0
     3     3     3     4     4     4    15    25    35    18    30    42     0     7     0
     3     3     3     4     4     4    20    45    10    24    54    12     0     0     7
```

Comment: Nice one! As the saying goes, better late than never. Though I no longer need it, this may be useful to others out there.